# Texture paint not saving

Tags: texture-painting

So today i was painting an object, when going to layout mode everything i painted is gone and the part returns back to gray color, ive tried everything but nothing fixes my problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add images of the problem to your question, preferably showing the whole screen.

Comment: what Blender version do you use? In the latest versions, when you close Blender, it should ask you if you want to save the pictures

Answer (score 1):

I’ve had the same problem before so I think I know what you’re doing, but I’ll clarify what *isn’t* the right way to save textures inside Blender:

1. Used a memory image texture created using Blender’s New Image button on the Image Texture shader node
2. Painted some stuff on the image (and maybe turned on automatically pack resources)
3. Saved the .blend file

…and when you open up the file again, it doesn’t work.

The problem with that process is *Blender saves images and the other stuff separately.*
You need to do steps 1 and 2, but then navigate to **Image*** (The * means that it hasn’t saved the image) and then click

[image: The option you want to click]

This will save the image inside of the .blend file, allowing you to save your texture along with it. (Also, you should probably turn on automatically pack external resources just to be safe, but that’s just my opinion.)